# How to search for alphanumeric word before or after a keyword in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have sentences as shown in the below examples:

```
$sen1 = "The quick brown fox jump KEYWORD over123 the3 lazy dog, fox is quick";

$sen2 = "The quick brown fox jump123 KEYWORD over the lazy dog, fox is quick";
```

i want to use the keyword 'KEYWORD' as my search string to extract the alphanumeric words before and after the search string using Perl regular expression.

sample output:

**over123**

**jump123**

NB: The word 'the3' is left out because i'm only searching for alphanumeric words exactly before or after the 'KEYWORD'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use named capture method, so that you don't need to check $1 or $2 if only one case is present. `(?<before>[\w\d]+)?\s*KEYWORD\s*(?<after>[\w\d]+)?`

```
my $str = <<DAT;
The quick brown fox jump KEYWORD over123 the3 lazy dog, fox is quick
The quick brown fox jump123 KEYWORD over the lazy dog, fox is quick
The quick brown fox jump123 KEYWORD over123 the lazy dog, fox is quick
The quick brown fox jump123KEYWORDover123 the lazy dog, fox is quick
DAT

foreach (split(/\n/,$str)){
    if(/(?<before>[\w]+)?\s*KEYWORD\s*(?<after>[\w]+)?/){
        print $+{before} . "-" . $+{after} . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, what about 1 or 2 words before or after the keyword?

Comment: So you need to get all the alpha numeric words before and after keyword?

Comment: Also in your question you said that 'the3' is left out because you are only searching for the words which are exactly before and after. So now if you want more words please explain with some examples.

Comment: yes that is correct, but for only 1st, 2nd or 3rd word before or after the KEYWORD

Comment: now i want the word 'the3' to be captured as well, if possible with words in 3rd position too since 'the3' is in 2nd position. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have your keyword that only appears once in your string, you could use this:

```
my $string = 'The quick brown fox jumps123 KEYWORD over the lazy dog';

my ( $w_before, $w_after ) = $string =~ m/(\w+)\s*KEYWORD\s*(\w+)/;
# $w_before == jumps123
# $w_after == over
```

I'm assuming that, when you say alphanumeric, you mean that it's either letters OR numbers OR combination of both. In that case, `\w` can do that. I also put `\s*` just in case there's space between the KEYWORD and the before/after word.

Using what I've written, it can capture the words 'blah' and 'foo' in:

```
blahKEYWORDfoo
blah KEYWORD foo
blahKEYWORD foo
blah KEYWORDfoo
blah          KEYWORD      foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any more stringent requirement for either target but that it be composed of at least one of either words or digits, something like

```
([\w\d]+)\s+KEYWORD\s+([\w\d]+)
```

ought to do you in both cases; that'll give you the word before in $1, and the word after in $2.

Comment: thanks alot, what about 1 or 2 words before or after the keyword?